# View logs of multiple git repositories

Tags: bash, git, xargs

I have git repositories in a directory. For example,

```
$ ls
repo1 repo2 repo3 repo4
```

I want to see the last *k* commit logs of the all repositories quickly.
(*k* is something like 3.)

For repo1, I can print the last 3 commit logs and go back to the directory like this:

```
$ cd repo1; git log -3 ; cd ../
```

But I do not want to repeat this for all the repositories. I'm looking for a smart way to do it easily. (Maybe use xargs?)

I'm using Bash.
Thank you.

Comment: FYI when you have to do things that way, use `pushd` instead of `cd` and `popd` instead of `cd ..`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Often it's pointless to use `xargs`, since `find` can execute stuff on its own:

```
find ~/src/ -maxdepth 2 -name .git -execdir git log \;
```

Explanation:

```
find ~/src/
```

Look for stuff under ~/src/. You can pass multiple arguments if you want, possibly as a result of a shell glob.

```
-maxdepth 2
```

Don't recurse deeply. This saves a *lot* of time, since hitting the filesystem is relatively slow.

`-maxdepth 2` will find ~/src/.git (if it exists) and ~/src/foo/.git, so it can be used whether you pass the repo directory itself or just the directory containing all the repos.

`-maxdepth 1` would work (and be easier on IO) if only you want to pass the repo directories themselves.

`-maxdepth 3` might have occasional use for certain source hierarchies, but for them you're probably better just passing additional directories to `find` in the first place.

```
-name .git
```

We're looking for the `.git` directory (or file! yes, git does that), because `-execdir` normally takes a `{}` argument which it passes to the command. The passed filename would just be the basename (so that e.g. `mv` works ... remember that `find` often works with files), with the working directory set to whatever *contains* that.

-execdir ... \;

Run a command in the repo itself. The command (here `...`) can include anything, notably `-` options which will not be interpreted by `find` itself ... except that `{}` anywhere in a word is the filename, a lone `;` terminates the command (but is here escaped for the shell), and `+` terminates the command but passes multiple files at once.

For this use case, we don't need to pass a filename, since the directory the program is run in provides all the needed information.

Answer (score 3):

I have something similar, which is easy to be changed to satisfy your requirement:

```
CODE_BASE=(/parentdir/to/your/repositories 
/another/parent/dirs
/another/parent/dirs/if/you/have
)
EXCLUDE_PATT="gitRepoYouWantToIgnore" #this is regex

for base in ${CODE_BASE[@]};do
    echo "##########################"
    echo "   scanning $base"
    echo "##########################"
    for line in $(find "$base" -name ".git"|grep -v "$EXCLUDE_PATT"); do
        line=$(sed 's#/\.git##'<<<"$line")
        repo=$(awk -F'/' '$0=$NF' <<<"$line")
        echo "##########################"
        echo "====> Showing log of Repository: $repo <===="
        echo "##########################"
        git -C "$line" log -3
    done
done
```

Save to `showlog.sh` for example, then execute it. You can add more `log` parameters to make the log output fit your needs.